# How can I copy just new and changed files with an Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a large (lots of dependencies, thousands of files) nodejs app that I am deploying with an Azure Devops YAML build and Azure Devops "classic editor" release pipeline.

Is there some way to copy JUST new and changed files during a file copy, not every single file? My goal is to reduce the time it takes to complete the copy files step of the deploy, as I deploy frequently, but usually with just changes to one or a few files.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About copying only the changed files into artifacts for releasing, if the changed files are in a specific folder , you can copy files in the specified folder by specifying `SourceFolder` and `Contents` arguments in the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#arguments) task.

If the changed files are distributed in different folders, I am afraid that there is no out-of-the-box method to only pick the changed files when using `copy file` or `PublishArtifacts` task.

As workaround, we could add powershell task to deletes all files (recursive) which have timestamp that is < (Now - x min), with this way Artifact directory contains of ONLY CHANGED files. More detailed info please refer this similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615690/tfs-2017-how-build-deliver-only-changed-files).

Alternatively, you can call [Commits-Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#examples) rest api through a script in the powershell task, and then retrieve the changed files in the response and then copy them to specific target folder.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the idea of using the commits-get=changes API call is a good one, I will try that.