# Running prettier/eslint only on changed files using TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, prettier, pre-commit-hook

Currently we are using TFVC based repo. Recently we started using `Prettier` paired with `eslint` for our project since we want to enforce consistency and formatting smoothly across the repo. Now I cannot seem to find a way to run `prettier` and `eslint` only on the changed files.

We are also using `Azure Pipelines` which builds the artifacts.

[Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html) docs has this hooks but this only works for `git` version control !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this with [**`lint-staged`**](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged)

```
npm install --save-dev lint-staged husky
```

Comment: i dont think this works for tfvc repos, because there is no concept of staging here

Comment: hmm valid point, may be you need something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615690/tfs-2017-how-build-deliver-only-changed-files